# Python socket connect_ex() seems to get stuck depending on OS

Tags: python, sockets, port-scanning

I'm running a port scanner on my home network. If I run it against devices on my home network, it only works on other Linux machines (physical machines not VMs). By "works" I mean it finds what few ports are actually open (ssh, mysql, sunrpc, and a couple others).

When scanning Windows and other miscellaneous iot devices it just hangs and never finishes. I can't seem to figure out where it gets stuck.

I think this might be the most relevant part of the code:

```
for port in range(begin, end):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        status = s.connect_ex((self.target_ip, port))
    except Exception:
        continue
    finally:
        s.close()
    if status != 0:
        continue
    try:
        service = socket.getservbyport(port)
    except Exception:
        service = "unknown"
    print("SERVICE: %-15s\tPORT: %-8d" % (service, port))
```

Comment: The default connect timeout on most operating systems is about a minute. This operates when the host is down or there is a host-side firewall. Connection refusals operate from hosts in your LAN or without firewalls, and operate more or less immediately.

Comment: Some machines send a reset for connection requests on unused ports. Others just remain silent. As mentioned, setting a shorter timeout would speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code so that I could simulate a run on my machine and it seems like it hangs because that very last `print` statement is not reached. But this is because your `continue` line within the `if status != 0` always comes back as "not 0", at least on my Windows 10 Pro machine.

```py
for port in range(begin, end):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        status = s.connect_ex((self.target_ip, port))
        print("DEBUG: ", status) # add this
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error: ", err) # add this
        continue
    finally:
        s.close()
    if status != 0:
        print("DEBUG: status was not 0") # add this
        # if this line is reached, we start at the top of the loop
        # skipping the try except and print below entirely.
        continue
    try:
        service = socket.getservbyport(port)
    except Exception:
        service = "unknown"
    print("SERVICE: %-15s\tPORT: %-8d" % (service, port))
```

Could you give this a shot and see if will shine some light on what might be wrong or let us know what kind of output you get. I was not able to currently run this on any Linux machine or IoT devices. I assume you are able to read the console output on each of your devices to have determined that it seemed like it was "hanging".

**Edit 1: More context for the hanging issue**

Let me give you some examples of what happens with this script on my network.

**CASE 1:** `'192.168.1.0'`
This address exists, but generally isn't used or assigned to anything. Hangs for about 20 seconds per port for me.

**CASE 2:** `'192.168.1.1'`
This is usually the router on the network. Responds immediately. Hangs for about 1 second per port that is scanned.

**CASE 3:** `'192.168.1.3'`
This device is in the network range, but no device is actively using it. Hangs for about 20 seconds per port (just like case 1).

So the long "hang" isn't that it is not working. It can basically mean the IP is wrong or there is no device being reached so the timeout limit is being reached for that socket connection attempt instead of raising an exception it just moves on.

**Edit 2**

Before iterating over a huge range of IP addresses and a wide range of ports per each IP address being tested. Sometimes it can be helpful to test assumptions 1 at a time by defining more control over a few ports and a specific IP address.

This is what I converted your code into to do that. If the `conn` is not `0` I am just considering that port closed no matter which error code came back for this case. We only care about the ones that respond with `0` because that indicates the operation succeeded.

```py
import socket

# Lets test just a few custom ports.
ports = [21, 22, 80, 8080]

# And test a specific IP address to test, 1 at a time.
ip = '192.168.1.1' # change this if needed

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

for port in ports:
    # loop through our small custom port range.
    try:
        conn = sock.connect_ex((ip, port))
        if conn == 0:
            print("Port [{}] open.".format(port))
        else:
            print("Port [{}] closed.".format(port))
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        continue

    try:
        service = socket.getservbyport(port)
    except Exception:
        service = "unknown"
    print("SERVICE: %-15s\tPORT: %-8d" % (service, port))

sock.close()
```

Comment: Hmmm on some devices it actually hangs on the first IP tried. Then after a minute or so it starts to run (110s are returned). It must get stuck on the first socket?  It then gets stuck again and never finishes. The Linux machine returns 111. Setting the s.settimeout() helps a little but the program still never finishes. It only runs completely and finishes if scanning LInux...

Comment: Linux returning 111 seems to be a "connection refused" on my windows machine I was getting the error 10061 which is the Microsoft error code for connection refused.

I am curious about your port range the `begin` and `end` values. And are you scanning IP addresses you know for a fact exist on your network or are you scanning a range of addresses that may or may not exist?

Comment: If you are starting from a range of IP addresses, for example starting at 192.168.1.0. this IP is part of the range but on a network this address isn't generally used. And by default many routers tend to start from `.1` for the end of the address such as `192.168.1.1` 

So if I run your code against the `.0` ending address my scan will also hang on that IP. And if I lower my range  for ports to scan to 80-81 just to test it and run it against the 192.168.1.1 address it should respond back with a `0` because routers tend to run a webserver on port 80.

Comment: True... but I think that the try/except should catch the error. And it does when scanning a Linux system. But for what it's worth, the ranges are 0 all the way up to 65535. And the connection refused is a good thing... I just don't know why it hangs

Comment: I edited my post to add some example cases for what happens to me. I think this is what is happening to you too but you are translating that same type of "hanging" effect as something is broken? Sorry this is dragging on I am trying to make sure I am having the same type of hanging as you. :)